# SDL2 and SDL_opengl_glext.h undefined external

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors, sdl-2, unresolved-external

I'm running across problems when trying to move away from gl3w in my SDL2 project. The reason I'm considering this is simply because I noticed my version of gl3w doesn't include "glAlphaFunc" but SDL_opengl_glext.h does.

It seems I need to define the following:

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#define GLX_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
```

So after I noticed SDL_opengl_glext.h exists I figured maybe I could simply include SDL_opengl.h and SDL_opengl_glext.h (as I do on iOS: SDL_opengl.h and SDL_opengles.h), but now I'm getting issues with undefined externals.

The lib files I'm currently referencing:

opengl32.lib;glu32.lib;SDL2.lib;SDL2main.lib;SDL2test.lib;SDL2_image.lib;SDL2_ttf.lib;SDL2_mixer.lib;libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_58.lib;libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_58.lib;libpq.lib;ssleay32.lib;libeay32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

My question is: With SDL2 can I link any other lib files to fix this issue, how do I correctly use SDL_opengl_glext.h? I don't see any clear documentation on this issue in particular.

Error Spew:

```
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindBuffer referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindBuffer
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindBuffer
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenBuffers referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenBuffers
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenBuffers
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBufferData referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBufferData
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBufferData
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDisableVertexAttribArray referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDisableVertexAttribArray
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDisableVertexAttribArray
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnableVertexAttribArray referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnableVertexAttribArray
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glEnableVertexAttribArray
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUseProgram referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUseProgram
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUseProgram
1>emitter.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertexAttribPointer referenced in function "protected: virtual void __cdecl MV::Scene::Emitter::defaultDrawImplementation(void)" (?defaultDrawImplementation@Emitter@Scene@MV@@MEAAXXZ)
1>drawable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertexAttribPointer
1>spineMV.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertexAttribPointer
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glActiveTexture referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::Shader::set(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::shared_ptr<class MV::TextureDefinition> const &,unsigned int)" (?set@Shader@MV@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$shared_ptr@VTextureDefinition@MV@@@4@I@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBlendFuncSeparate referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::Draw2D::defaultBlendFunction(void)" (?defaultBlendFunction@Draw2D@MV@@QEAAXXZ)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBlendEquationSeparate referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::glExtensionBlendMode::setBlendEquation(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?setBlendEquation@glExtensionBlendMode@MV@@QEAAXII@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glAttachShader referenced in function "public: class MV::Shader * __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadShaderCode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadShaderCode@Draw2D@MV@@QEAAPEAVShader@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glCompileShader referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadPartOfShader(unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadPartOfShader@Draw2D@MV@@AEAAXIAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glCreateProgram referenced in function "public: class MV::Shader * __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadShaderCode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadShaderCode@Draw2D@MV@@QEAAPEAVShader@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glCreateShader referenced in function "public: class MV::Shader * __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadShaderCode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadShaderCode@Draw2D@MV@@QEAAPEAVShader@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGetActiveUniform referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,bool)" (??0Shader@MV@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGetProgramiv referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,bool)" (??0Shader@MV@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGetShaderiv referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MV::Draw2D::validateShaderStatus(unsigned int,bool)" (?validateShaderStatus@Draw2D@MV@@AEAAXI_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGetShaderInfoLog referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MV::Draw2D::validateShaderStatus(unsigned int,bool)" (?validateShaderStatus@Draw2D@MV@@AEAAXI_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGetUniformLocation referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,bool)" (??0Shader@MV@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glIsProgram referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int,bool)" (??0Shader@MV@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glLinkProgram referenced in function "public: class MV::Shader * __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadShaderCode(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadShaderCode@Draw2D@MV@@QEAAPEAVShader@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glShaderSource referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MV::Draw2D::loadPartOfShader(unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?loadPartOfShader@Draw2D@MV@@AEAAXIAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUniform1i referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::Shader::set(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::shared_ptr<class MV::TextureDefinition> const &,unsigned int)" (?set@Shader@MV@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV?$shared_ptr@VTextureDefinition@MV@@@4@I@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUniform1fv referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::Shader::set(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float)" (?set@Shader@MV@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glUniformMatrix4fv referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::Shader::set(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class MV::TransformMatrix const &)" (?set@Shader@MV@@QEAAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBVTransformMatrix@2@@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindRenderbuffer referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::startUsingFramebuffer(class std::weak_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer>,bool)" (?startUsingFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAAXV?$weak_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDeleteRenderbuffers referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Framebuffer::~Framebuffer(void)" (??1Framebuffer@MV@@QEAA@XZ)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenRenderbuffers referenced in function "public: class std::shared_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer> __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::makeFramebuffer(class MV::Point<int> const &,class MV::Size<int> const &,unsigned int,class MV::Color const &)" (?makeFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@AEBV?$Point@H@2@AEBV?$Size@H@2@IAEBVColor@2@@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glRenderbufferStorage referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::startUsingFramebuffer(class std::weak_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer>,bool)" (?startUsingFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAAXV?$weak_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBindFramebuffer referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::startUsingFramebuffer(class std::weak_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer>,bool)" (?startUsingFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAAXV?$weak_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@_N@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glDeleteFramebuffers referenced in function "public: __cdecl MV::Framebuffer::~Framebuffer(void)" (??1Framebuffer@MV@@QEAA@XZ)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glGenFramebuffers referenced in function "public: class std::shared_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer> __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::makeFramebuffer(class MV::Point<int> const &,class MV::Size<int> const &,unsigned int,class MV::Color const &)" (?makeFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@AEBV?$Point@H@2@AEBV?$Size@H@2@IAEBVColor@2@@Z)
1>render.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glFramebufferTexture2D referenced in function "public: void __cdecl MV::glExtensionFramebufferObject::startUsingFramebuffer(class std::weak_ptr<class MV::Framebuffer>,bool)" (?startUsingFramebuffer@glExtensionFramebufferObject@MV@@QEAAXV?$weak_ptr@VFramebuffer@MV@@@std@@_N@Z)
1>C:\git\MoonDog\x64\Release\M2tMLibrary.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 33 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you use OpenGL extensions. You need to load extension functions at run time with `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress` or use any of existing [opengl loaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

If you only need this one function you can define its prototype yourself or load it at runtime. Note that newer GL vesions deprecated `AlphaFunc` (which is the reason why gl3w don't have it - as it targets GL 3 or higher), so you cannot use it if you target these versions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that as well, and I was using gl3w as an opengl loader. It appeared as if SDL2 included an opengl loader, (that's what I thought SDL_opengl_glext.h might be.)  I figured I might have been missing a function call similar to gl3wInit(); but wasn't sure.

Do you know what SDL_opengl_glext.h is supposed to be for if not opengl loading?

Thanks for the heads up on AlphaFunc, so I should just include that in my shaders then!  I may just stick with gl3w if SDL2 doesn't have an opengl loader, I'd like to give you a chance to read this comment, but so far I may accept your answer

Comment: `SDL_opengl.h` and `SDL_opengl_glext.h` are just portable replacements for `gl.h` and `glext.h`. `glext.h` itself is rarely used, even more so with `GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` define active (without it it provides type definitions for function pointers - may be useful if you write your own extension loader). I'm pretty sure you can use gl3w with SDL as the solve very different things (SDL+glew is very common too). All that SDL provides in terms of GL function loading is portable `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress`, but then again you only care about it if you write extension loader.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this clears some confusion.  I used to load my own extensions, and a few years ago moved to gl3w to just do it for me, and hadn't thought of it again until AlphaFunc came up in an example with stencil buffers and I looked into how to load that function (which I don't need as it's deprecated anyway and I can do it in my shaders). Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

[What is an undefined reference / unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

You need to link to SDL2main.lib
Then to SDL2.lib
Then any other SDL libraries.

Make sure you're linking to a binary that's fine by your compiler, and of the right architecture.

If all else fails, compile SDL yourself.